# app.setWindowIcon(icon) works only sometimes

Tags: qt, ubuntu, pyqt, pyside

I am developing an application in PySide and I need to set the main application icon which will be shown in the system task bar. Basically I call it like this:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon('appicon.png')
```

On Windows everything works fine all the time. However when I run it in Python interpreter `python myapp.pyw` on Ubuntu, it sometimes shows the icon in the task bar, sometimes not. It is unpredictable, however I observed that when the icon is shown correctly then it is likely to be shown correctly for several subsequent application runs. If it does not show correctly, then the subsequent runs are also likely to fail. As if it is somehow cached or something like that.

In the log file, I can see that the png file was loaded fine every time (even in cases when it is not shown in the task bar), I check that with printing icon.availableSizes(). My icon is 43x43 pixels (I guess this is not the proper size of icons in the task bar) but I do not know if it matters.

So the question is how to make the icon show every time?

Comment: Smells like a WM bug.

Answer (score 1):

You should setWindowIcon in the init function of your mainwindow class instead, like this:

```
..
self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/path/to/image/image.png")))
```

And NOT in the main function of your program (I assume that's what you're doing), even though it might work sometimes.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the cause of my problem. With `app.setWindowIcon('appicon.png')` I am setting the default window icon for windows which do not have their icon specified. I tried your suggestion however and it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('appicon.png'))
It works with me.